# How do we regulate(prevent/allow) access from one Azure resource to another?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-active-directory, cloud

In AWS, roles are attached to resources(lambda, ec2) to prevent or allow access to another resource. How is it done in Azure? What service  is used in Azure for this?

Comment: Hi @Vishal,

Please go through this tutorial and you should able to configure resource specific access.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/tutorial-restrict-network-access-to-resources?source=docs#restrict-network-access-to-a-resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day, Vishal Daniel, just like AWS has IAM, Azure uses what is called Role-Based Access Control, popularly known as RBAC. Azure role-based access control (Azure RBAC) helps you manage who has access to Azure resources, what they can do with those resources, and what areas they have access to. Just as you would give EC2 full access to an S3 bucket, you can also use Azure RBAC to give resources as well as individuals permissions to your resources or resource groups. you can read more from the link below: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview